# Arquillian: path relative to project instead of server

Tags: java, path, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

How can I use a project-relative path when using Arquillian/Shrinkwrap to test my testcases?

```
IDataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(new File("src\\ZZZZZ.xml"));
insertFromXML(dataSet);
```

Will give me this exception when testing 
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Uprogs\jboss-eap-6.2.4\bin\src\ZZZZZ.xml`

It tries to locate the file within the folders of the server on which I deploy the test onto.
Rather than that, I want him to look in the folders relative to my project (e.g. `C:\Users\xy\workspaces\MyProject\src\ZZZZZ.xml`). Searched the internet but found nothing

Shrinkwrap gets deployed like this:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    File[] libs = Maven.resolver()  
            .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").resolve(
                    "jcifs:jcifs"
                    , "org.dbunit:dbunit"
                    , "com.ibm:db2jcc_license_cisuz"
                    , "com.ibm:db2jcc"
                    )  
            .withTransitivity()
            .asFile();  

    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addAsLibraries(libs)
            .addPackage("de.abc.RuleEditor")
            .addAsResource("de/abc/RuleEditor/messages.properties", "messages.properties")
            .addAsManifestResource("test-jboss-deployment-structure.xml","jboss-deployment-structure.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("test-beans.xml", "beans.xml")     
            .addAsWebInfResource(
                    new StringAsset("<faces-config version=\"2.0\"/>"), "faces-config.xml")
                    .merge(ShrinkWrap.create(GenericArchive.class).as(ExplodedImporter.class)  
                            .importDirectory("src/main/webapp").as(GenericArchive.class), "/", Filters.include(".*\\.xhtml$"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use a project-relative path when using Arquillian/Shrinkwrap (...)?

It's a ridiculous approach, don't go that way :]

The idea behind Arquillian is to create micro-deployments (it means: `jar/war/ear` archive using `ShrinkWrap` tool) and include everything inside that archive.

So please modify your deployment:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {

return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
        (...)
        .addAsLibraries(libs)
        // Add in below way any additional file to the archive
        .addAsResource("path-to-testset.xml", "dbunit/testset.xml")
        .addPackage("de.abc.RuleEditor")
        .addAsResource("de/abc/RuleEditor/messages.properties", "messages.properties")
        .addAsManifestResource("test-jboss-deployment-structure.xml","jboss-deployment-structure.xml")
        (...)
}
```

And then use `getResourceAsStream()` to load file from the class path:

```
@Test
public void test_something() {
   FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
   builder.setColumnSensing(true);

   FlatXmlDataSet xmlDataSet = builder.build(
            this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dbunit/testset.xml"));
  // ...
```

It is much better, as everything what is needed to test, is already included inside archive. No relative, nor absolute path names.

My personal advice is: be careful about `DbUnit`, as perhaps you notice in the future, crafting and managing many xml data sets may become bigger and bigger problem as your project will grow. That is why I prefer [DbSetup](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/).